Can I use a WHERE in the SELECT arguments?
My SQLite database has rows containing columns pst_id and clicked_at (among others). In order to get a count of the rows connected with a specific pst_id I use
SELECT pst_id,count(*) FROM consolidated_results
GROUP BY consolidated_results.pst_id

If I want to further filter by the non-empty clicked_at fields, I use
SELECT pst_id,count(*) FROM consolidated_results
WHERE consolidated_results.clicked_at != ''
GROUP BY consolidated_results.pst_id

Is it  possible to combine the two to get both results simultaneously? Something like (invalid code)
SELECT pst_id,count(*),(count(*) WHERE consolidated_results.clicked_at != '') FROM consolidated_results
GROUP BY consolidated_results.pst_id

to get a results such as



pst_id
count(*)
count(*) WHERE WHERE consolidated_results.clicked_at != ''




10
1256
34


20
65242
59



Note: my main problem with this probably obvious question is that I do not know what to look for (combining SELECT and WHERE in queries yield results for the normal filtering)

From SQLite 3.30.0 you could use FILTER otherwise a case expression would do what you are asking
SELECT pst_id,
       count(*) as tot_count, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE clicked_at != '') as clicked_at_count
FROM consolidated_results 
GROUP BY pst_id;


This is the preferred way, if available.

Conditional aggregation can be done by applying a CASE statements in the aggregation expression for SUM, COUNT, MAX, AVG, etc., as in:
SELECT pst_id,
  count(*),
  count(case when consolidated_results.clicked_at != '' then 1 end)
FROM consolidated_results
GROUP BY pst_id

The COUNT(<expression>) function will count only non-null evaluated values. Therefore, any row that doesn't match the predicate, won't be counted.
